# Word for "assuming others believe the same things you do" that isn't "projection"

Tags: single-word-requests

I've often heard "projection" used for this colloquially but from what I can tell the somewhat formal definition of "projection" seems to require doing so as a defense mechanism such that you deny that you feel the way you do while assuming that others feel the same way as you sans the denying part.

Is there a word for this notion without the self defense part, that is more or less free of any kind of value judgement on the part of the person holding the belief or the person(s) assumed to be holding the belief, and free of any kind of intentionality, e.g. I want you to believe what I believe?

For example,

> Sorry, I'm ____  again. I shouldn't have assumed that.

Comment: "Project" doesn't require psychological self-defence although it's often used in that context. [Lexico's](https://www.lexico.com/definition/project) examples include "Then again, maybe I'm just projecting my own political behaviour onto a wider section of the public than is justified." Here "project" seems to mean assuming everyone behaves the same. Regardless, another name for the phenomenon is the [False consensus effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_consensus_effect), which might help searching.

Comment: Related: [A more general version of "projecting"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/404381/a-more-general-version-of-projecting/408568#408568) and more closely [What is a single word for a false assumption of similarity, namely through empathy?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314670/what-is-a-single-word-for-a-false-assumption-of-similarity-namely-through-empat)

Answer (score 2):

> Sorry, I'm **presuming** again. I shouldn't have done that.

*Presume* is a bit stronger than *assume*.

**presume** (v.)

> To expect or assume especially with confidence [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presume)

> Take for granted that something exists or is the case. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/presume)